# Sub-query executes 1 time for a parent query or more?

Tags: mysql, select

If i apply a static data in where clause is it faster then applying a sub-query. Example:

(The query returns 5 records as a result set)

`SELECT STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM TEST WHERE STARTDATE = '2012-08-21';`

is faster then :

`SELECT STARTDATE, ENDDATE FROM TEST WHERE STARTDATE = (SELECT STARTDATE FROM TEST2 LIMIT 1);`

or they are same in any case?

Sub-query executes each time a comparison perform by query with each record or only for 1 time?

Comment: You need parenthesis there, not quotes: `WHERE STARTDATE = (SELECT STARTDATE FROM TEST2 LIMIT 1)`

Comment: You know you can test that. Just create a big enough `TEST` table, say 1M rows.

Comment: Yes i can do it but still i want some internal workings, it would more beneficial for others too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to MySQL 5.6, the inner query is executed once per entry in the outer row and is easy to prove:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample_data;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        8 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sample_data WHERE id = (SELECT SLEEP(1) );
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (8.00 sec)
```

Note that the query takes 8 seconds, thus the SLEEP(1) is executed 8 times, once for each row in `sample_data`.

MySQL 5.6 has implemented [subquery materialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) which, in theory, will prevent this from happening in many cases.  MariaDB also has a greatly improved optimizer that should prevent this.

In most cases, it is preferable to avoid subqueries in MySQL.

Comment: Correct .. I am using 5.1 and can see the results using sleep are taking too much time (records * sleep time).

Comment: MariaDB 10.3.7 takes 8 seconds.  Perhaps the optimizer recognizes `SLEEP()` as special and avoids subquery materialization?

Comment: 5.6.22 takes 8 seconds.  Nice try, but something funny is going on.

Answer (score 5):

As Aaron posted, MySQL optimizer is sometimes plain dumb. If you are not working with MariaDB latest versions (and you can't wait for MySQL 5.6 to be released), you can still "fool" the optimizer into running the subquery once, by moving it from the `WHERE` to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT t.STARTDATE, t.ENDDATE 
FROM 
    TEST AS t 
  JOIN 
    (SELECT STARTDATE FROM TEST2 LIMIT 1) AS s
  ON t.STARTDATE = s.STARTDATE ;
```

Comment: If we use `JOIN` with sub-query is not it retrieve the data for each record?

Comment: No, the subquery will be usually executed once (check the EXPLAIN plan, it will show a "Derived" table in the "Select_type" column)

Comment: Thank you - i am checking [mysql execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)